# Display same content twice in WPF Button

Tags: wpf, button, styles, contentcontrol

We want to style a wpf button so that the content set in the button is displayed twice. The reason for this is that we want to achieve a drop shadow effect of the button's content. Out thought was to have two ContentControls in the Button style like below:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
<ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Foreground="White" Margin="0,1,0,0" />
```

So, one ContentControl is for displaying the real content and one ContentControl is for displaying the same content with a little margin so that it gives the effect of being the drop shadow. The problem is that it doesn't show content in both content controls. Only one of them shows content. How can I successfully show content in both content controls?

Also, the dropshadow effect is not an option since the button's content becomes blurry.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The second ContentControl doesn't have a ContentTemplate binding, and you should always also bind the ContentTemplateSelector, trust me, this will save you a lot of annoying bug hunting. Also you should read about the ContentPresenter and its use in ContentControls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know there are differences in using ContentPresenter and ContentControl in templates. The reason I'm using contentControl here is to be able to set the Foreground property of the contentControl. This way I can control the Foreground depending on the VisualState (Pressed button etc). The ContentPresenter doesn't have a foreground property. The ContentTemplate doesn't make any difference and using 2 ContentPresenters doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

**Buttons with Nested Content**:

```
<Style x:Key="ShadowButton"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid>
          <Rectangle Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                      ElementName=presenter}"
                      Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                                      ElementName=presenter}">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
              <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left"
                            Stretch="None"
                            Visual="{Binding ElementName=presenter}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
              <TranslateTransform X="3"
                                  Y="3" />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
          </Rectangle>
          <!-- You can replace the following line to a ContentControl if you absolutely have to -->
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="presenter"
                            ContentSource="Content" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage can then be dynamic like:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="36"
        Style="{StaticResource ShadowButton}">
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Margin="2"
            Content="A" />
    <Button Margin="2"
            Content="B" />
    <TextBox Margin="2"
             Text="Blah" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

By using a `VisualBrush` your not having 2 `ContentControl` / `ContentPresenter` in your Style and are just rendering one into a `Brush` to fill a rectangle and get your effect.

**Duplicating Visual Tree with a Template**

Try to have a `UserControl` do this than a `Button` in the first place. You need to use a Template if you want to duplicate the Visual Tree in your style.

```
<Style x:Key="ShadowButton"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid>
          <ContentControl x:Name="shadow"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Foreground="SpringGreen">
            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
              <TranslateTransform X="50"
                                  Y="50" />
            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
          </ContentControl>
          <ContentControl x:Name="presenter"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Foreground="SlateBlue" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger SourceName="presenter"
                    Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="shadow"
                    Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Teal" />
            <Setter TargetName="presenter"
                    Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Red" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

and usage:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Style="{StaticResource ShadowButton}">
  <Button.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <Button Margin="2"
                Content="A"
                Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                    AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
                                      Path=Foreground}" />
        <TextBox Margin="2"
                  Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
                                      Path=Foreground}"
                  Text="Blah" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Comment: Changing the template like this will remove the option to use it with custom data, because now lacking the ContentPresenter. While i understand this in the sake of explaining, it should be noted that this is not good practice.

Comment: I use ContentControl instead of ContentPresenter because I need to change Foreground of the Button's content depending on visual state. Your solution would work if the Button's content is text only. However, it won't work if you're having custom content in the button's content (fore example a stackpanel with multiple child elements)

Comment: @dowhilefor Yes this Style posted would be specific for a Button with just Text Content for the Shadow Effect. It does not lack a ContentPresenter tho (it still uses it in the style) only the effect is bound to the ContentPresenter's Text property which if the button was holding other child elements and had this Style would not work. Am Updating the answer to accommodate for any nested Child controls.

Comment: Thanks for your updated reply! I actually tried this solution previously and the problem is that the VisualBrush always is rendered as an exact copy of the Content so I cannot get it in another color. I need the dropshadow in white and the Content in another color that also need to change depending on Visual State :-)

Comment: Well you need to understand that when you set Content you have "1" Actual Visual Tree. You thus cannot end up adding it to 2 different elements in your style, You need to use a template to do this. However you should actually be making the entire control a separate UserControl tbh. I'll update my answer with a work-around but do consider making the control into a UserControl than doing this on a button.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in a small dummy application and it works just fine. See if this is what you want.

```
     <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="test" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"/>
                            <ContentControl Foreground="DarkGray" 
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}">
                                <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2" X="2"/>
                                </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource test}">
            Test
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nope, it doesn't work. It works for just string content but not for complex content such as 

    <Button Style="{StaticResource test}">
        <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
    </Button>

Comment: well there is no easy way to solve this then, the best is propably now to utilize a VisualBrush for the shadow effect, while only maintaining one content.